# Necessary to have Retina and non-Retina for all images in iOS App?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, retina-display

Currently , all the UIImageViews in my app are set to scaleToFill mode, using only one retina image without setting any non-retina image. I suppose that on non-retina display, the extra resolution will be lost by itself.

Question: Is this approach acceptable? And will Apple disapprove my app due to the missing non-retina images for UIImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple won't reject your app. However it's recommended to have non-retina versions if you're targeting Universal devices, since there are still lot of non-retina iPad out there, and scaling is slower and sometimes produces ugly images.

If you're targeting iPhone only, (IMO) there's no need for non-retina images.

Comment: Your last statement is only valid if the app only supports iOS 7. There are still non-retina iPhones that support iOS 6 or earlier.

Comment: No, it's not about iOS versions, it's about the device generation. iPhone 4 (and older) are the only devices that uses non-retina images.

Comment: I believe iPhone 4 is using retina display. So what @rmaddy said is correct.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen It's both. If the app is iOS 7 only then no non-retina iPhones are supported because iOS 7 only runs on retina iPhones. The iPhone 4 is retina. But if the app supports iOS 6 then you need both sets of images because iOS 6 runs on both types of iPhones. But if you also support iPad then you need both because the non-retina iPad 2 runs iOS 7.

Comment: If my app is supporting iOS6 and have only one set of Retina images, all UIImageViews' size are half of the image's resolution and set to scaleToFill, what will happen on non-Retina display (except a bit slower due to scaling)? And Apple will still approve?

Comment: If you try to use retina images on a non-retina iPhone, you'll probably run into memory pressure rather quickly. Retina images use more memory (higher resolution), and the non-retina devices have less memory than the retina devices. Just open your images in an editor, scale them to 50%, and you're done.